# How to get display mode

Tags: android, screen-resolution

My android device has a `Display Mode` under `Settings -> Display` page. This display-mode settings screen displays various display modes such as `480i, 480p, 720p, 1080p, 1080i` etc... 
My device has Android OS version 2.3.3. Please note, this is a custom made Android device.

When I select any of these display modes, my device's mode get changed. I need to get the currently selected display-mode value programatically.

Is there any way this can be done ?

The `Settings` screen
[image: The <code>Settings</code> screen]

The `Display Settings` screen
[image: The <code>Display Settings</code> screen]

The `Output Mode` spinner
[image: The <code>Output Mode</code> spinner]

Comment: Such as this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/android-how-to-get-screen-dimensions

Comment: May you can use the density to get what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166501/getting-the-screen-density-programmatically-in-android

Comment: @QVDev that post deals with screen dimensions. what i need is the display mode set currently for the system. As this [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/480p) indicates, 480p itself can have several resolutions. So i may need to keep some tables to calculate the screen-mode. But this can be erroneous. Somewhere this settings must be stored in the system and it should be retrieved via some system properties. rt ?

Comment: @viperbone your link calculates the screen density. How can i get the display-mode from screen density ?

Comment: I can't see a Diplay Mode settig. Which version of Android do you use? Could you also post a screenshot of the setting?

Comment: @viperbone i just added screenshots. plz have a look. thxs

Comment: @viperbone My device has OS version 2.3.3 in it. Please note this is a custom made android device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a solution.

**First way**

I saw an app named [About](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.whph.android.about). This application lists `SystemProperties` as list with `propertyname` and `value`. From this, i got the required property name as `ubootenv.var.outputmode`.

Then i got another thread which reads the `SystemProperties` using the `getprop` android command from here : [Parsing Android getprop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944747/parsing-android-getprop)

By this way, now i am able to get the `display-output-mode` parameter.

**Second way**

I also tried using `android.os.SystemProperties` class via reflection and tried invoking `get` method. But this is returning `null` always.

Anyway the first method is working. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Both "ubootenv.var.outputmode" and "display-output-mode" didn't get me anything. How did you get it? I've found some apps that somehow get the real, max display resolution, such as these : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.andr7e.deviceinfohw https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.drhowdydoo.displayinfo . I think they find all the display modes, but what I've found of the official API ( https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display#getSupportedModes() ) doesn't seem to work like what they got.

Answer (score -2):

```
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    final Point size = new Point();

    try{
        display.getSize(size);
    }catch(NoSuchMethodError nsme){
        Log.w(TAG, "@ Error caz of display.getSize() : " + nsme);
        size.x = display.getWidth();
        size.y = display.getHeight();
    }
```

`getSize()` supports from API level 13. That's why we need to use a try catch block.

Comment: here i get the screen size rt ? how can i get to the display-mode from this ?

Comment: You are not talking about orientation (Landscape/Portrait). Are you?

Comment: Yes you are right. I am not trying to get screen orientation. please have a look at the edited post for screenshots. thxs